# Deriving a sentence - Predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

$\forall x(Fx \lor \neg Fx) \rightarrow Ga \vdash \exists x Gx$

1) ∀x(Fx v ¬Fx) → Ga   Premise

2)¬∃xGx   Premise (Negation of conclusion)

3)∀x¬Gx   Quantifier negation

4)¬Ga     Universal installment

5)¬∀x(Fx v ¬Fx) Modus Tollens

6)...

I dont know how to do this derivation. My attempt might be ineffective. Some help/tips please? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What specific inference rules do you have?

Comment: Can you prove $Ga \vdash \exists xGx$?

Comment: I have all the rules of Sentenial Logic plus Universal Installment,  Universal Generalization, Existential Generalization, Quantifier Negation , E

Comment: Git Gud, i can prove the one that you said, however i am not sure how to deal with proving this.

Comment: Can you prove that $\forall x(Fx \lor \neg Fx)$? Can you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: Do you have anything to instantiate an existential with? What is that last rule E?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: ... and you're still not using Mathjax .... I put the first line in Mathjax ... can you please do all others?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  I don't know if you have the inference rules to do this, But I would follow with:

$6. \exists x \neg (Fx \lor \neg Fx) \quad Quantifier \ Negation \ 5$

$7. \neg (Fb \lor \neg Fb) \quad Existential \ Installment \ 6$

$8. \neg Fb \land \neg \neg Fb \quad DeMorgan \ 7$

$9. \neg Fb \quad Simplification \ 8$

$10. \neg \neg Fb \quad Simplification \ 8$

$11. Fb \quad Double \ Negation \ 10$

$12. Contradiction \ 9,11$

Comment: You could reach a contradiction one step earlier due to 9 and 10.

Comment: Wait a second. I am not sure if existential installment is an actual rule? Can we really go from ∃x¬(Fx∨¬Fx) to ¬(Fb∨¬Fb) ?

Comment: @AmandaO That's what I just asked: do you have a rule like that?  If not, then this obviously doesn't work for your system ... so then try Git Gud's suggestion: don't do this by a proof by contradiction, but try and prove $\forall x (Fx \lor \neg Fx)$

Comment: @GitGud true ... though I have seen systems where you can only get contradiction between atomic statements and their negation so I tried to be safe ... though it now looks as if my assumption that there would be some kind of existential elimination was wrong ...

Comment: @AmandaO $\exists x~\neg\text{Stuff}(x)$ means that there does exist some value, let us call it $b$, where we witness that $\neg\text{Stuff}(b)$.  ... providing the token $b$ does not already occur free in the predicate $\neg\text{Stuff}(x)$.  It *should* be among your ruleset.

Comment: The altenative would be to show that $\neg\forall x~\text{Stuff}(x)$ is a contradiction by assuming $\forall x~\text{Stuff}(x)$ and demonstrating that it is a tautology.